# Maven can't load groups for JUnit categories out of a class with multiple interfaces?

Tags: maven, junit, interface, categories

My Maven:

```
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.15</version>
                <configuration>
                    <groups>
                        com.rubberduck.TestState.Ready
                    </groups>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
```

My Class:

```
package com.rubberduck;
public class TestState
{
    public interface Ready {
        /* to allow filter ready tests as groups */
    }    
    public interface InProgress {
        /* to allow filter ready tests as groups */
    }    
    public interface NotTested {
        /* to allow filter ready tests as groups */
    }    
}
```

My Test:

```
@Test(timeout = 60000)
@Category(TestState.Ready.class)
public void test() throws Exception {
    assertEquals(true, true);
}
```

My Error:

```
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.14.1:test (default-cli) on project rubberduck: Execution default-cli of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.14.1:test failed: There was an error in the forked process
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to load category: com.rubberduck.TestState.Ready
```

If I give him `<groups>com.rubberduck.TestState</groups>` it compiles without error, but I want to have multiple interfaces for groups in the same class, isn't that possible?

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19981320/where-should-i-put-interface-class-for-junit-category

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can specify interfaces within classes like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.15</version>
    <configuration>
        <groups>
             com.rubberduck.TestState$Ready
        </groups>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try making the interface definitions static but this begs the question, why not just define each interface in its own file? This in no way changes your ability to use them or assign multiple of them to a JUnit test.

Comment: static makes no difference, still claims "unable to load". I have multiple groups and I wanted to maintain them all in one file. I'm not a big fan of 3-line java classes :D