# Where should I put interface class for Junit @Category?

Tags: maven, junit, integration-testing, maven-surefire-plugin

**I'd like to define project-wide interfaces, to be used in `@Category` annotations, and configure Maven to exclude their annotated tests when building the whole project.**

In the *application* project there's a test I'd like to categorize:

```
@Category(Integration.class)
@Test
public void testExternalResource() { ... }
```

### The setting:

I've set up a multi-module maven project:

```
/container (has a pom with <modules> element)
    /parent (all other modules inherit from its pom. has no source, only pom)
    /util (other modules are depending on it)
    /infra
    /application (depending on infra and util, inherits from parent)
```

Being an infrastructure freak :), I'd like to configure my whole project to exclude groups in any module. So, in *parent* module I've defined:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.16</version>
    <configuration>
         <excludedGroups>com.mycompany.test.Integration</excludedGroups>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

And I've put the `Integration` interface in the *util* module (in the `util/src/test/java`), for all modules to see:

```
package com.mycompany.test;
public interface Integration {}
```

And because it's a `test-jar`, [I've made the right configuration](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-attached-tests.html) for both *util* and *application* .

### The error:

When running `mvn clean install`, I'm getting

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:
    maven-surefire-plugin:2.16:test
    (default-test) on project util: Execution default-test of goal
    org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-surefire-plugin:2.16:test
    failed: There was an error in the forked process
[ERROR] java.lang.RuntimeException:
    Unable to load category: com.mycompany.test.Integration
```

Well, of course the class isn't available - I've crammed it in a test-jar in the first module of the project. :(

**Where should I put my `Integration` interface so it will be available to my mvn configuration and my source code?**

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Create a new Maven module and put the interface under `src/main/java/`. Make sure `junit` is available as a compile time dependency (`<scope>compile</scope>`) - you're basically building a dependency that other tests can use. So your code that helps other tests must go into main while the tests for this go in the `src/test/java`, as usual.

This step feels a bit weird but think about how you would package `junit` itself. From the point of view of `junit`, it's just a normal Java library, so all its code goes into `main`.

When you need this module, use it as a test dependency with `<scope>test</scope>`

Comment: This of course requires that this new module wouldn't inherit from the parent pom that uses it? I'll try that

Comment: You can have a cyclic dependency with a parent POM. For this, the parent POM must have `<packaging>pom</packaging>` which means it doesn't actually try to load the dependencies which you define there. If the parent POM is the actually the one for the main code, create a second Maven project.

Comment: parent: has no source, pom packaging